# sharepoint users cannot edit their workflow tasks

Tags: sharepoint, workflow, edit, task, permissions

I've created a custom workflow using Visual Studio 08 that uses a custom content type and .aspx task edit form. The tasks are successfully created and assigned to the users. However, only users that are members of the Site Owners group are able to 'Edit' the task items. All others (even though they have contribute and approve permissions) cannot browse to the custom task edit form in the _layouts directory but instead receive the standard "Access Denied" page.  The task list's item-level permissions are also set to allow users to read and edit all items not just their own, yet it still doesn't work.

Giving these users Site Owner permissions in order to be able to edit their tasks is not an option for us. Is there any solution or workaround to this issue?

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

If you're using any SharePoint Designer workflows, this could be the problem:

https://www.ericshupps.com/sharepoint-designer-workflows-tasks-and-the-annoying-access-denied-error/

> **SharePoint Designer Workflows, Tasks, and the Annoying “Access Denied” Error** by  Eric Shupps
>
> […]
>   After futzing with it a bit, I tried something different – I checked the workflow out, then checked it back in (right-click the workflow folder in SPD, Check-Out/Check-In). Voila! Users can now edit their own tasks. Bizarre. It's worth noting that this only happened for me on workflows that were created by the System Account – regular users with Site Owner permissions did not experience this problem (your mileage may vary).

Comment: I've updated the link (thanks to Julia Washburn). I've also quoted some relevant parts from the external site to save your answer from being deleted as a Low Quality (link-only) answer. Please review the edit to make sure I included the right bits.

Answer (score 0):

I would say go to Site Settings>Advanced Permissions>Permission Levels, click on the Contribute permission level and view its settings - maybe someone unchecked a List or Site Permission?

Users with Read permissions should be able to view custom forms in the /_layouts/ folder. I would also check the file permissions in the 12 hive just in case.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, Ajay. I verified that the Contribute permission level is as expected. I even created a new permission level with all the settings copied from the Full Control permission level, then applied that permission level to the user group for the task list only (though this is still highly undersirable) just to see what it would do, and still nothing. Weird huh? 

I also checked the ACL permissions on the layouts folder. Tried giving the Everyone group full control (again just to see where that took me) but nothing. 

Any other ideas are appreciated.

Comment: Can you access the workflow form in a different site collection or web app as a member? Check how widespread this problem is.

Comment: The workflow form requires certain query parameters (e.g., the task list id) which won't be found in a different site collection.  Not sure how I could test for that...

Comment: For a different site collection on the same web app, just create a task using your custom workflow and open the task.

For a different web app, deploy your custom workflow to this web app, then create a new site collection and do the above.

Comment: I see what you mean.  Well I have deployed the workflow to two different servers with the same results.

Comment: Ajay, It seems that at a minimum users must have Design permissions at the subsite level in order to be able to edit workflow tasks or start workflows.  (http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/sharepointworkflow/thread/1f1df076-ae72-4a63-8f0f-485a8e74c291).  This is not ideal.  If this is inconsistent with what you've found, please let me know.  Thanks...